# loops do not work perfectly

Tags: php, loops

i have a script is like this

```
    if(strtolower($command) == "s") {
        $result = ig($options);
        for($i=0; $i < count($result); $i++) {
        $ImageCarouselTemplateBuilder = new \LINE\LINEBot\MessageBuilder\TemplateBuilder\ImageCarouselTemplateBuilder([
          new \LINE\LINEBot\MessageBuilder\TemplateBuilder\ImageCarouselColumnTemplateBuilder($result[$i],
          new \LINE\LINEBot\TemplateActionBuilder\UriTemplateActionBuilder('Buka Browser',$result[$i])),              
          ]);
        }
        $templateMessage = new \LINE\LINEBot\MessageBuilder\TemplateMessageBuilder('nama template',$ImageCarouselTemplateBuilder);
        $result = $bot->replyMessage($event['replyToken'], $templateMessage);
        return $result->getHTTPStatus() . ' ' . $result->getRawBody();
    }
```

as you can see, I keep the loops in the line 3, with the number of loops corresponding to the count of my function (3 loops), but the script does not run perfectly, the result of the above script only responds to the first loop object only, for the second and thirdly there is no response.
is there any suggestion to solve this problem?

the results I get from the script above is like in the picture below

[Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bagtN.jpg)

and I want the response as in the picture below

[Picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTKdc.jpg)

Comment: You're `return`ing inside the loop.

Comment: I've tried it, and it did not work

Comment: By did not work you mean what exactly? post your loop in the question

Comment: If you really must use images, please upload it using the image tags in the Question edit box. External links may disappear one day.

Comment: You may need an array with more than one elements to the parameter of ImageCarouselTemplateBuilder class.